# $\phi(x) := \tan({\frac{\|x\|\pi}{2\epsilon}})\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is defined on the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I have the information that it is defined on the open ball $B_{\epsilon}(0).$ But, How can I be verify?
In fact, I have to verify that this functions is a diffeomorphism between the open ball and $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: What is $g$ and $t$? In what space does your open ball live?

Comment: @Mankind, $tg$ means the tangent function, it is all defined on the $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am sorry, I will be more explicit.

Comment: I believe that the answer should be along the lines of [the inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Manifolds).

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the fact that $\phi$ is well-defined, smooth and bijective between the two spaces, doesn't make it a diffeomorphism. It's inverse has to be differentiable as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\be}{\mathcal{B}_\epsilon} \renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}$As discussed by @Mankind, $\phi$ is defined as a mapping
$$
\phi:\be\setminus\{0\} \to \Re^n\setminus\{0\}.
$$
(1) The function is **surjective** as we can see in the following figure.

[image]

The domain of $\phi$ can be written as the union for all $\partial\bar{\mathcal{B}_{\kappa\epsilon}}$ for all $\kappa\in(0,1)$. These spheres are mapped to

$$
\begin{align}
\phi(\partial\bar{\mathcal{B}_{\kappa\epsilon}}) &= \{y=\phi(x) : 
\|x\|=\kappa\epsilon, \kappa\in(0,1)
\}\\
&=\{y=\tan\left(\frac{\kappa\epsilon\pi}{2\epsilon}\right)v:  \|v\|=1, \kappa\in(0,1)
\}\\
&=\{\alpha v: \|v\|=1, \alpha\in \left(0, \tan\left(\frac{\kappa\pi}{2}\right)\right)\} 
\end{align}
$$

Every $y\in\Re^n$ can indeed be written in the form $y=\alpha v$ with $v=y/\|y\|$ and $\alpha=\|y\|$ for an appropriate value of $\kappa\in(0,1)$.

(2) $\phi$ is *injective*. Indeed, if there are two $x,y\in\Re^n$ with $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$, then $\|\phi(x)\|=\|phi(y)\|$, therefore $\|x\|=\|y\|$. It is then easy to verify that $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ using the definition of $\phi$. Therefore, $\phi$ is *bijective*.

(3) The domain of $\phi$ is an open set and $\phi$ is continuously differentiable thereon. Take $p\in\be$, $p\neq 0$ and compute the Jacobian matrix of $\phi$ at $p$, $J\phi(p)$. According to the [inverse function theorem](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~nwallach/inverse%5B1%5D.pdf), if $J\phi(p)$ is nonsingular, then $\phi^{-1}$ is differentiable at $p$. It then suffices to show that
$$
\det J\phi(p) \neq 0, \forall p\in \phi(\mathcal{B}_\epsilon\setminus \{0\}).
$$

I tried to derive $J\phi(p)$ in closed form and I did so using MATLAB, but the result is frustratingly complex...

Nevertheless, we may define the function $\phi_\kappa: \partial\bar{\mathcal{B}}_{\kappa\epsilon}\to \partial\bar{\mathcal{B}}_{\tan\left(\frac{\kappa\pi}{2}\right)} $ as
$$
\phi_\kappa(s) = \tan\left(\frac{\kappa\pi}{2}\right)\frac{s}{\kappa\epsilon}
$$
which we can see that they are diffeomorphisms between $\partial\bar{\mathcal{B}}_{\kappa\epsilon}$  and $\partial\bar{\mathcal{B}}_{\tan\left(\frac{\kappa\pi}{2}\right)}$. Roughly speaking, this means that as $s$ moves on the orange sphere in the figure, $\phi_k(s)$ moves smoothly on the red sphere and vice versa. Now, for a fixed vector $s$, as $\kappa$
changes, the two spheres will be inflated/deflated accordingly and this is also done in a smooth way since $\gamma_s(\kappa) = \tan(\frac{\kappa\pi}{2})s/\kappa\epsilon$ is a diffeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and the semiline defined by $s$.

I must admit I don't know how to rigorously combine the two diffeomorphisms to conclude that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, but we know that if we focus on spheres and on semilines, $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and, furthermore, all the directions of the space can be decomposed into directions on spheres and directions of inflation of those spheres (i.e., generalised $n$-dimensional polar coordinates). This said, $\phi$ must be a diffeomorphism.

Comment: sorry about the late. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if the function
$$f\colon B_{\epsilon}(0)\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$$
given by
$$f(x) = \tan\left(\frac{||x||\pi}{2\epsilon}\right)\frac{x}{||x||}$$
is well-defined. It is a matter of checking that everything you do is an allowed operation. Remember that for $\tan(y)$ to make sense, you need $y$ to be different from values of the form $\pi/2+k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer. For all other values of $y$, the expression $\tan(y)$ makes sense.

We certainly have that $0\leq\frac{||x||\pi}{2\epsilon}$, and whenever $x\in B_{\epsilon}(0)$, then since $||x||<\epsilon$, we also get
$$\frac{||x||\pi}{2\epsilon}<\frac{\epsilon\pi}{2\epsilon} = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
In total,
$$0\leq \frac{||x||\pi}{2\epsilon}<\frac{\pi}{2},$$
and the function $\tan\left(\frac{||x||\pi}{2\epsilon}\right)$ makes sense.

So all is well until here, but the function $f$ fails to be well-defined at $0\in B_{\epsilon}(0)$ as it is, since we divide by $0$ in the expression $\frac{x}{||x||}$. See the comments.

Comment: What do you mean that $0\notin B_\epsilon(0)$. Isn't $B_\epsilon(0)$ the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$? What is more, you need to show that $\phi^{-1}$ is also differentiable. Finally, $\phi$ is a differomorphism between $B_\epsilon(0)\setminus 0$ and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$, right?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis yes, you are correct, of course. For some reason, I thought of the boundary of the ball. I suppose the function is not well-defined on $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ as it is, but that you can patch it up at $x=0$ by using $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\tan(||x||\pi/(2\epsilon))}{||x||} = \pi/(2\epsilon)$.

Comment: @Mankind, thank you! But remains one question, how do I know that this function has as domain the open ball?

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi it doesn't. The function is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: @Mankind, define the function as $0$ if $x=0$, now, I suppose that it is defined on the open ball, but why? I mean, how do I know that the domain is the open ball?

Comment: $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon$ is an *open* ball. Since $\phi$ is defined for $x\in\mathcal{B}_\epsilon(0)$, i.e., for $\|x\|<\epsilon$, we have $\frac{\|x\|\pi}{2\epsilon} \in [0, \pi/2),$ so the domain of $\phi$ is $\mathcal{B}_\epsilon\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: thank you! This is exactly what I intended to know.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi I don't see how this post answers the question. One needs to show that $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, which means that $\phi^{-1}$ must be differentiable.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis, exactly, you are right. The problem is that this question is open for so long, I don't imagine that anyone would give a more detailed answer. If you are able to do one, I will really appreciate and rethink about the best answer. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi I'm trying...

Comment: @LeonardoFranciscoCavenaghi Just to clear up any possible confusion: My post shows that the given function is defined on $B_{\epsilon}(0)\setminus\{0\}$, and it does not show that it is a diffeomorphism from this set onto $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$If $x = ru$ with $r = \|x\| \geq 0$ and $u$ a point on the unit sphere, and if $\phi$ denotes the unique continuous extension to the origin, as seemed clearly intended, then
$$
\phi(x) = \left(\tan \frac{r\pi}{2\eps}\right) u.
$$
Bijectivity is immediate, as are smoothness of $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ except possibly at the origin.

To establish smoothness of $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ at the origin, define
\begin{align*}
f(r) &= \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{r} \tan \frac{r\pi}{2\eps} & r \neq 0, \\
  1 & r = 0,
\end{cases} \\
  &= 1 + \frac{\pi^{3}}{24\eps^{3}}\, r^{2} + O(r^{4}).
\end{align*}
Particularly, $f$ is real-analytic at $0$, and $\phi(x) = f(\|x\|) \cdot x = x + O(\|x\|^{2})$ at the origin.